# Is there a way to sort result based on value of another column?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table that looks like below:

```
[Col A  Col B
000000  null
000924  000244
000244  000000
000758  000000][1]
```

I want to be able to query and get the output sorted in such a way that, ColA displays values beneath the value specified in Col B. Example: '000758' and '000244' should appear below '000000' and '000924' should appear below '000244'. Please see below for expected output:

Expected Result:

```
[Col A  
000000
000758
000244  
000924][1]
```

Comment: can you share your latest coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: Don't know how Oracle handles null in sorting, but otherwise I think you want `select colA order by cola,colb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a hierarchical query with `ORDER SIBLINGS BY ...`:

```sql
SELECT colA
FROM   table_name
START WITH colb IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR colA = colB
ORDER SIBLINGS BY colA DESC
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ColA, ColB) AS
SELECT '000000', null     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '000924', '000244' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '000244', '000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '000758', '000000' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | COLA |
> | --- |
> | 000000 |
> | 000758 |
> | 000244 |
> | 000924 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=856189cc422429f136ef3cc7073fbb4e)*

Comment: @user19384928 If it solves your question, then please consider checking the flag to accept this answer.

Comment: you can simplify it to `SELECT colA FROM table_name ORDER BY colb asc nulls first, colA desc`

Comment: @IłyaBursov That may coincidentally get the same order for this sample data but that method does not order it based on the OP's requirements as described in the question.